# Qt hide QToolBar and access shortcuts

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar, key-bindings

I am using Qt version 4.8.6.
I am trying to develop an application where only couple keyboard keys are used, without mouse. I have added some actions to my main QToolBar and assigned shortcuts to those actions.

[image]

Now I can either click on them or use the assigned keyboard keys to trigget the "triggered" signal. This is a debug feature however and in the end I would like to hide that toolbar. So to test it, I have used:

```
ui->mainToolBar->setHidden(true);
```

Toolbar dissapeard as I intended but the problem is that my assigned shortcuts stopped working. Is there a way to hide the toolbar but keep the actions shortcuts?

Comment: Use `QShortcut` class